# select and add the values for duplicated record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sum if any values  if it exists in any of three columns for the duplicated unit number. Getting error if I use below query. any help appreciated. Thank you

```
select RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY unitNumber order by tableA.id) as unitnumber, ColA, ColC, ColB 
from tableA join 
     tableB on tableA.id = TableB.id
where unitNumber > 1
  and tableB .adm_Date between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013

Data:

 unitNumber colA  colB   ColB
  235       402   88     null
  245       null  501    522
  255       110   550    null
  245       85    null   101
  215       90    null   20
  275       852   225    null
  215       70    null   20
  225       null  null   null
```

The output should be

```
  unitNumber   colA    colB    ColB
    235         402     88     null
    245          85    501     623------added the values in colA, ColB
    275         852    225     null
    215         160   null     40 ------added the calues colA and ColB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need ranking functions. All you need is group by UnitNumber. I am basing the query based on your source and destination data.

```
SELECT UnitNumber, SUM(ISNULL(ColA, 0)) ColA, SUM(ISNULL(ColB, 0)) ColB, SUM(ISNULL(ColC, 0)) ColC 
from tableA join 
     tableB on tableA.id = TableB.id
where unitNumber > 1
  and tableB.adm_Date between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013
GROUP BY UnitNumber
```

Assuming all the data is in the same table

```
SELECT UnitNumber, SUM(ISNULL(ColA, 0)) ColA, SUM(ISNULL(ColB, 0)) ColB, SUM(ISNULL(ColC, 0)) ColC 
from tableA 
where unitNumber > 1
  and tableA.adm_Date between 01-01-2013 and 12-31-2013
GROUP BY UnitNumber
```

Comment: Thanks @Anup Agarwal. Since I have few other calculated columns included in select statement, is there a way to write the above isnull in 'where' clause. Tried using 'having' but did not work.

Comment: @user3502587 If there are other calculated columns you can use add in `Select` clause also you can have them in `having` clause. If you can show show more data, it will be easier to understand what you are asking. Also just to avoid the moving goalpost situation, if it is totally new question it is better to start a new thread.

Comment: I used case ...when..then to populate colA, colB and colC. I also have ids and codes column. Used above 'sum(nullif)' and 'group by' with case...when..statement, but still not adding up duplicate unitnumber. any helpappreciated.                                    
 id unitNumber colA  colB   ColB    code
 51    235       402   88     null   tx
 52    245       null  501    522    cg
 53    255       110   550    null   fw
 54    245       85    null   101    mx
 55    275       852   225    null   tx
 56    215       70    null   20     mx
 56    225       null  null   null   mx

Comment: What is tableA and TableB. Is it the same table? What is the purpose of code field. If all your data is in 1 table, I have updated my answer.

Comment: all the columns are from tableB, Used tableA only to get the date range. I need to send this data as .csv to update different applicationDb table. so when I import this .csv file ,this applications throws error when it encounters a duplicate unit_number(but it can have duplicate IDs). That's the reason I need  to add the values for duplicate unit_number.(also, when I try above query, it asks to aggregate all remaining columns, if I include,the uit-number is still duplicated). Hope I included all the points. Thanks you